# arrow function in object literal can't access values of the object

Tags: javascript

On access suit or value inside the arrow function the code give following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: suit is not defined
>           at Object.toString (VM378 script.js:4)
>           at VM429 script.js:7

```
let card = {
  suit : "Spades",
  value : "Queen",
  toString : () => suit + " of " + card
};

console.log(card.toString());
```

Comment: Use a `function` (or method) and reference `this.suit`, etc

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `card` variable in that case, like this:

```js
let card = {
  suit : "Spades",
  value : "Queen",
  toString : () => card.suit + " of " + card.value
};

console.log(card.toString());
```

That happens because the arrow functions will take the current context (`this`) and you will not be able to do `this.suit`. However, if you use the `function` syntax, you can do:

```js
let card = {
  suit : "Spades",
  value : "Queen",
  toString : function () { return this.suit + " of " + this.value }
};

console.log(card.toString());
```